# ionic localstorage wont load for the first time

Tags: ionic3

i have a problem when i want to do authentication for a user to check is this user already login or not. The side menu will be different for users if they are login or not. i am using localstorage to save the token of user from API. this is the way i save token in login.ts.

```
localStorage.setItem("token",this.data.token);
```

after that i want to use the localstorage to check is the user already login or not using this condition

```
 if(localStorage.getItem("token") !== null && localStorage.getItem("token") !== ""){
  console.log("already login, token :"localStorage.getItem("token"));
  this.isLoggedIn=true;
}
else{
  console.log("not login")
  this.isLoggedIn=false;
}
```

this condition doesnt run on the first page reload, but if i reload the browser it works.
I already put this condition inside ngOnInit(), ionViewWillEnter(),constructor() and nothing help this problem

Comment: Which storage are you using? Ionic’s Storage? Or  web api based localStorage?

Comment: Can you share full code to see whats initial value of isLoggedIn you have?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a promise based syntax for saving/retrieving values from local storage.

```
    this.localStorage.get('token').then((value) => {
    // Do your side menu stuff
    this.isLoggedIn=true;
    });
```

Also checkout : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app for a similar use case where Side Menus are enabled/disabled based on , if a user is logged in or not

Hope this helps..

Comment: Your answer assumes that the storage is Ionic’s Storage which is using promises indeed, but in the question the methods user (getItem etc) hint that it is web api simple storage which is supposedly synchronous. Just saying that your answer might be miscontexted until the author can confirm what they are using